# Couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it - React Native - Expo?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

After ejecting the Expo project using `expo eject`, and try to run the project using Xcode "11.7" & Command-line "For **iOS**"

I got these errors,

Note:

> Android Works well after ejecting
>
> iOS & Android Works well before Ejecting.

**Xcode**

```
Details

The file “MyApp” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.
Domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain
Code: 257
Failure Reason: You don’t have permission.
Recovery Suggestion: To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.
User Info: {
    NSFilePath = "/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bnfffrwsrhskljawuujrmpuwldgt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app";
}
--
The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 13
Failure Reason: Permission denied
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.14.6 (Build 18G95)
Xcode 11.7 (16142)
```

**Architectures**

[image: Architectures]

**Command-line**

> npx react-native run-ios

```
info Found Xcode workspace "MyApp.xcworkspace"
info Launching iPhone 11 (iOS 13.7)
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme MyApp -destination id=60F7E669-0AE4-4CF3-9BC8-17027D01B172")
success Successfully built the app
info Installing "/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-bnfffrwsrhskljawuujrmpuwldgt/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app"
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=1):
This app could not be installed at this time.
Could not install at this time.
Failed to chmod /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/60F7E669-0AE4-4CF3-9BC8-17027D01B172/data/Bundle/Application/3C7513F0-9BFE-4C94-A722-7C1BE6898E54/MyApp.app/MyApp : No such file or directory
Underlying error (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=4):
        Failed to chmod /Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/60F7E669-0AE4-4CF3-9BC8-17027D01B172/data/Bundle/Application/3C7513F0-9BFE-4C94-A722-7C1BE6898E54/MyApp.app/MyApp : No such file or directory
info Launching "com.MyApp"
error Failed to launch the app on simulator, An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=1):
The request to open "com.MyApp" failed.
The request was denied by service delegate (SBMainWorkspace) for reason: NotFound ("Application "com.MyApp" is unknown to FrontBoard").
Underlying error (domain=FBSOpenApplicationErrorDomain, code=4):
        The operation couldn’t be completed. Application "com.MyApp" is unknown to FrontBoard.
        Application "com.MyApp" is unknown to FrontBoard.
```

Answer (score 1):

- **Failure Reason:** You don’t have permission.

First of all please be sure that delete the **derived data**

If it didn't work then change **permission for Terminal**. Detail link is [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/443611/how-macos-catalinas-new-security-features-work/)

---

Probably you would not need this but just in case :

Maybe disabling system integrity protection with `csrutil disable` works for you.

Highly recommend you to read the [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/disabling_and_enabling_system_integrity_protection) first.

Comment: Thanks, But no way to solve this issue without Disable System Integrity Protection?

Comment: Sadly, No not works :((, Note I have Mojave Not Catalina, and this issue just with this project!

Comment: no it is all about general settings not for specific for Catalina, and your project related with this answer.

Comment: okay Thanks, But I swear :3 it does not work for me!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when I used react-native to create a new project.I had solved this problem.

System Information
macOS Version 10.14.4
Xcode 11.3.1 (16142)

run "react-native --version" in project directory.  The version is "react-native: 0.64.0". I used "npx react-native init interview --version 0.63.4" to create a new project.It worked!

So I guess use the older version to create a new project can solve your problem.